# Error with class(charactervector) <- "Date"

Tags: r, class, date

The following does not work:

```
today <- as.character("2016-09-13")
class(today) <- 'Date'

today
## [1] NA
```

> ```
> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In as.POSIXlt.Date(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
> 2: In as.POSIXlt.Date(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
> 3: In as.POSIXlt.Date(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
>     as.numeric(a)
> ```

Whereas this does work:

```
today <- as.character("2016-09-13")
a <- as.Date(today)

a
## [1] "2016-09-13"

as.numeric(a)
## [1] 17057
```

I'd like to have the a solution to make `class(today) <- 'Date'` work and understand why it is not working.

Comment: Dates are stored as number, not character, so R can't render a character vector with a Date class. In addition to coercing to Date class, `as.Date` parses the character vector to the appropriate number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `class<-` function does not trigger any conversion/coercion code. The `class<-` function maps to the [R_do_set_class](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/159691fa7529fc9ae6d9009faf84f9b8a1cf4464/src/main/coerce.c#L2801) function in C code. And ultimately you wind up at a code branch where [they explicitly don't do the coercion](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/159691fa7529fc9ae6d9009faf84f9b8a1cf4464/src/main/coerce.c#L2794).

Look at these two examples

```
today <- as.character("2016-09-13")
class(today) <- 'Date'
dput(today)
# structure("2016-09-13", class = "Date")

today<-as.Date("2016-09-13")
dput(today)
# structure(17057, class = "Date")
```

Notice how an S3 "class" is just a named attribute on a structure in R. It tells R how to interpret the value in that structure. If you manually set the class to something incompatible with the value (as you might do with `class<-`), you run the risk of breaking things.

Also notice that you don't get the error unless you try to print the value of `today`. That's because the re-assignment "works" but when R goes to use the value (as when printing), things get messed up because it's not stored in the way R expect.,

The lesson really is that `class<-` should not be used for conversion between different class. It it only use to fiddle with the class attribute of an object.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at

```
today <- as.Date("2016-09-13")
unclass(today)
# [1] 17057
typeof(today)
# [1] "double"
```

It is a `"double"` (numeric), not a string. The correct way to give class, is via:

```
a <- structure(17057, class = "Date")
# [1] "2016-09-13"
```

or

```
a <- 17057
class(a) <- "Date"
a
# [1] "2016-09-13"
```

If you start from a character string, use `as.Date`.

Comment: I don't get your point. If you do `today <- as.Date("2016-09-13"); class(today)` then you'll also get `"Date"`

Comment: As to your edit. I'm starting from a character string, and I want to change it to a Date using `class(characterstring) <- "Date"`

Comment: Zheyuan Li. I mean to ask, why does it have to be an integer? You can do this: `a <- as.character("2016");class(a) <- "numeric";a`. Why doesn't this work: `a <- as.character("2016-09-13");class(a) <- "Date";a`.